# What approach and package to use to make Authentication in Laravel + react app?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, authentication

I am building some applications with Laravel as the backend and react as the front end. So, I used the standard Laravel instruments - session, Auth facade, and custom controller. It works because I put react in the resources/js folder and connected it in one blade view file (It uses the same domain as the Laravel app). However, I hesitated a little. Is it Okay to use standard session auth while using react? Or should I use JWTt (I haven't learned how to use JWT yet)?

I tried to use laravel/breeze, but I got a lot of errors like (cors, csrf, 419, 401), and I can't make it up with laravel starter kits. So I feel like standard auth using a session is the most comfortable, So I need advice; what should I use? Is it okay to use just session auth like it using with a blade in the standard Laravel app? If you have some good tutorials about the Laravel + React app, I would appreciate it if you share them because I've watched a lot and still can't make it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be stressed about it, JWT is very simple and easy just go through some blogs/videos and you can understand it pretty well. Here are some links ...

https://blog.logrocket.com/implementing-jwt-authentication-laravel-9/

https://blog.pusher.com/laravel-jwt/

https://youtu.be/jIzPuM76-nI

I have built so many projects using Laravel 8 and Laravel 9 with React Front-end.

Build APIs in Laravel with JWT auth token security and just implement it in your React Frontend.

I hope this info can help you.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've found very good video that helped me. So I made it up with Laravel breeze

Answer (score 0):

Don't be stressed out.

You can do it just by the sanctum package.

It provides CSRF protection and follows natural Laravel session authentication flow.

I use Laravel and ReactJS completely separate.

Make some wrappers and use them without a headache.